# Why isn't Chrome reading changes to my website's CSS, even though iOS Safari and Firefox is able to?

Tags: html, css, web-hosting

When I'm working on my code and open the files in Chrome, they look correct. But after I upload them to my Hostgator server, the new changes I added aren't being reflected in the browser. Safari on iPhone 6S and Firefox in Ubuntu are reading the correct CSS from the server, but Chrome on both Ubuntu and Windows is still reading the old code.

I attached a .gif link so you can see what I'm seeing, plus my Github repo link and a link to the live site. I also included my HTML plus a CodePen. Please let me know if I can make my question any clearer and thank you!

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
  <title>Rodolfo Eduardo, Writer and Entrepreneur</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://rodolfoeduardo.com/book">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="columnContainer">
    <div class="outerColumn">
        <div class="aboutlogocontainer">
          <a class="mainLogoContainer" href="home">
             <img class="mainlogo" alt="mainlogo" src="Images/favicon-194x194.png"/>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="hamburgler-menu">
          <ul class="hamburgler-menu-list">
            <li><a class="navigationItem" href="about">About</a></li>
            <li><a class="navigationItem" href="poems">Poems</a></li>
            <li><a class="navigationItem" href="essays">Essays</a></li>
            <li><a class="navigationItem" href="contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="hamburgler" class="hamburgler-icon-wrapper">
          <span class="hamburgler-icon"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="innerColumn">
      <h1 class="pageTitle">Books</h1>
      <div class="igContainer1">
        <div class="bookRow1">
          <p class="bookCopyTitle2">I have two options for everyone:</p>
          <p class="bookCopy">Amazon (paperback)</p>
          <div class="bookImgContainer">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0999501305" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><img class="polaroid" src="Images/polaroid.jpg"/></a>
            <p class="bookCopy">Etsy (ePub)</p>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.etsy.com/"><img class="etsyphoto" src="Images/etsy.jpg"/></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="iconAboutContainer">
        <div class="iconAboutSubContainer">
          <div class="vscoAboutContainer">
            <div class="vscoicon">
              <a href="https://vsco.co/rodolfohernandez"><img class="iconAboutImages" src="Images/vscologo.png" alt="VSCO Logo" /></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="igAboutContainer">
            <div class="instagramicon">
              <a href="https://www.instagram.com/rodolfo.eduardo/?ref=badge"><img class= "iconAboutImages" src="Images/instagramlogo.png" alt="Instagram" /></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('hamburgler').addEventListener('click', checkNav);
    window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 27) closeNav();
    }, false);

    function checkNav() {
      if (document.body.classList.contains('hamburgler-active')) {
        closeNav();
      } else {
        openNav();
      }
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.body.classList.remove('hamburgler-active');
    }

    function openNav() {
      document.body.classList.add('hamburgler-active');
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

- Gif of problem: https://giphy.com/gifs/xT1R9Yct45D610t2RG
- Repo: https://github.com/rodolfohernandez/RH-Writing-Website
- Live site: https://rodolfoeduardo.com/books
- Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OOQJgP

Comment: Might be the page is being loaded from browser cache. Try to load your new site in incognito mode and check if everything is in place.

Comment: @abskmj I tried that but no luck, thank you though!

Comment: Can you see if your css changes are available at https://rodolfoeduardo.com/CSS/style.css

Comment: @abskmj nope, I guess somewhere between generating the file and uploading it something is messed up. I'll keep working on it and update the question

Comment: Looks fine from here. The styles for `.bookCopyTitle2` and `.bookCopy` match what's shown in your animated GIF.

Comment: @JonathanNicol seems like the issue is with Chrome. Safari on iPhone 6s with current software and updated Firefox on Ubuntu show the code fine. Chrome isn't updating the website's CSS file, it's still using the old version even after a cache clear.

Comment: I viewed the site in Chrome

Comment: @JonathanNicol wow then maybe it's just my systems? I'll have to check with some other people's machines then, because my Chrome in both Ubuntu and Windows 10 (tablet and PC) don't seem to be updating the code. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Not sure why, but my server was reading the .jpg files as text, so I uploaded .png files and made the necessary changes to the code. So far everything seems to be working now, not sure if that did it, but thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U probably are having a cache issue in your browser.try clearing cache and open your website again.In chrome you can use Ctrl+Shift+R to refresh and clear cache at the same time in your browser tab

Comment: Tried but still the same issue. Thank you for your answer though, I guess I'm not asking the right question the right way based on the downvotes. I'll come back and see if I can get it right